# Can Conditional Models be used for Individual Predictions?

Tags: regression

I was looking at this paper on Conditional Models and Marginal Models :https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat770/LeeNelder2004.pdf .

Based on my understanding of this, it seems like Marginal Models are intended to model the overall effects averaged over all individuals whereas Conditional Models (I think these are synonymous with Random Effects Models) are intended for specific individuals.

For example, if I have a group of patients and I have several observations for each of these patients over a period of time. A separate Conditional Model would be fit to each of these individuals - **does this mean that if a new patient were to enter the study, we could not be able to use any of these Conditional Models that we previously created for this new patient?**

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Your distinction -- marginal models for population effects, conditional models for individual effects -- is a simplistic summary of what the Lee & Nelder paper says. The abstracts ends with: "We regard the conditional model as fundamental, from which marginal predictions can be made."

Comment: @ Dipetkov: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you recommend any references in which this is further elaborated on - how can marginal predictions be made from conditional models"? thank you so much!